# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_executable)

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch, libtorch

I am trying to build a simple CNN model using Pytorch C++ API ( libtorch ), but when I try to run CMake it gives me this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_executable):
Cannot find source file:
    
      
training_VGG.cpp 
    
Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
    
    
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: example
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "example".

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project(Digit-Recognition-MNIST)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

add_executable(example training_VGG.cpp)

target_link_libraries(example "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

set_property(TARGET example PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: You're compiling `training_VGG.cpp` and you're saying that it is located directly at the project directory. Either is not there or not called that way.

Comment: Relative source paths are resolved against the cmake source dir at the time of creating the target; In this case the source dir is it refers to the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file you posted.